# Android: Scale a view like image?

Tags: android

I was creating a banner layout for our App and it turns out that there are essentially two options I have:

- Have a static image for the banner
- Create a banner layout that actually lays out individual elements of the banner image. This option enables changing the banner content at runtime.

Initially, I thought that creating a dynamic banner(option 2) should always be the way to go(unless you have time crunch) but it turns out if the layout is to be changed in width and height, the margins, dimensioning and position of the views might change. As an example, if there is a `TextView` that is supposed to take up only single line might *spill over* to second line if the width is shrunk. This is the case with the dynamic layout.

With static layout, overall image would scale down therefore, although the font size would go down a bit, the text would remain in one line only.

Now, this seems to be the obvious disadvantage with dynamic layouts, is there any way I can fix it...like maybe scaling up/down a view like an image instead dynamically adjusting the positioning and whatnot for the views involved?

Or, having a static banner design is preferred?

Comment: I always prefer dynamic over static. In your scenario, if you set your constraints right in a Constraint Layout and use autosizing textviews you wouldn't have the issue described.